# PHP/MySQL image retrieval and display by user-defined location and time

Tags: php, mysql, image, data-retrieval

What I'm trying to do is code a PHP search page that will retrieve a user-uploaded image(s) via a MySQL database where the images are stored by reference and where the search may be done by user, location and date. That is, the user, who registered as being from a specific city, state and postcode,  gives the location and date of the image, which is then stored in a folder, and one can then search images by user, location and date. The search results are displayed in an ASPX page.

I've got the following code so far. Right now the results.aspx page just displays little red X's.

**search_locations.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">



<title>Search Images</title>



<style type="text/css" media="screen">
ul li{
  list-style-type:none;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h3>Search Locations</h3>
<p>You may search either by city, state/province or postal code</p>
<form method="post"  action="../search.aspx?go" id="searchform">
<label id="city">City</label>
<input type="text" name="city">
<label id="state">State or Province</label>
<input type="text" name="state">
<label id="postcode">Zip (Postal) Code</label>
<input type="text" name="postcode">

<fieldset name="Date">
<legend>Date</legend>

                <legend>Month</legend>

                <select name="Month">
                <option>January</option>
                <option>February</option>
<option>March</option>
<option>April</option>
<option>May</option>
<option>June</option>
<option>July</option>
<option>August</option>
<option>September</option>
<option>October</option>
<option>November</option>
<option>December</option>
</select>
<legend>Day</legend>
<input type="text" name="day">          
<legend>Year</legend>
<p>20<input type="text" name="year"></p>
            </select>

</fieldset>
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit'])){

    $s = $_REQUEST['search'];
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("userdata") or die(mysql_error());
    $sql ="select image from userdata where image= '%".$s."%' ";

    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

    if($count != 0){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
      echo $row['firstname'].'<br>';
      echo $row['lastname'].'<br>'; 
      echo $row['city'].'<br>';
      echo $row['state'].'<br>';    
          echo $row['country'].'<br>';  
          echo $row['image'].'<br>';
          echo $row['imagetime'];

        }
    }
    else{
      echo 'Error Message';
    }
}



?>


<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">

</form>




</body>
</html>
```

**userdata.sql**

```
INSERT INTO `userdata` (`id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`,`phone`,`state`,`city`,`postcode`,`country`,`gender`,`dob`,`image`,`imagetime`) VALUES (NULL,'Joseph','Blow','jblow@yo.com','909-555-1234','California','San Bernardino','92407','USA','M','01011990','../upload/jblow/jblowdate1.jpg','02142016');
INSERT INTO `userdata` (`id`,`firstname`,`lastname`,`email`,`phone`,`state`,`city`,`postcode`,`country`,`gender`,`dob`,`image`,`imagetime`) VALUES (NULL,'Helena','Noe','helnoe@yo.com','909-555-5678','California','San Bernardino','92407','USA','F','02021990','../upload/hnoe/helnodate1.jpg','06012016');
```

**search.aspx**

```
Search Results
<br/>
<br/>
<img src="upload/<?php echo $row['image']; ?>">
<br/>

<img src="getImage.php" width="175" height="200"/>
```

Anybody want to help me out with this?

Comment: Where do you expect `$row` to be defined in your `search.aspx` file? Also why do you have PHP code in an ASP file?

Comment: $row is the id of the user, and under these conditions it would be displaying all the user's photos, only the user might very well have more than one photo, so I think I would want to be able to (1) display more than one photo (2) by not just user but location and time. The PHP code displays the image. You're saying I don't need it.

Comment: I guess the line of code with the php code doesn't need to be there.

Comment: The image still won't display. Is the database not being called.? Anybody got any ideas?